Layered structured bindings
Say I have some code like this:
std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>> data = {...};
for (const auto& [index, coords_tuple] : std::views::enumerate(data))
{
    const auto& [begin, end] = coords_tuple;
    //Use begin and end
}

Is it possible to use the structured bindings in a layered manner:
const auto& [index, [begin, end]] : std::views::enumerate(data)

Or even better:
const auto& [index, begin, end] : std::views::enumerate(data)

Of course those don't work directly, but is there a way to get them to work?

Not yet. You need a 2 step binding.

@Red.Wave Ok, fair enough.

Side note : why aryou even using a std::tuple here? It is the wrong kind of lazy, you want to model coordinates, then model coordinates e.g. struct myCoordinate { std::size_t x; std::size_t y;}. Your code will become more easy to use and you will have better semantics.
